# pthread_exit() and pthread_join() don't work

Tags: c, pthreads, pthread-join, pthread-exit

I don't know why it doesn't return the value that I type in. I know it's not the `void* arg` because it prints the right number, but I don't have any idea.

CODE:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


void* stampa(void* arg) {
    float dato = *(float*)arg;
    printf("Read: %f\n", dato);
    
    pthread_exit((void*)&dato);
}

// Main
int main() {
    system("clear");

    pthread_t miot;
    int creathread;
    float x;
    float *status;

    printf("Number: ");
    scanf("%f", &x);

    creathread = pthread_create(&miot, NULL, stampa, (void*)&x);

    if (creathread != 0) {
        printf("Error\n");
    }

    pthread_join(miot, (void*)&status);
    printf("Returned: %f\n", *status);

    return 0;
}
```

RESULT:

```
Number: 10
Read: 10.000000
Returned: 0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
void* stampa(void* arg) {
    float dato = *(float*)arg;
    printf("Read: %f\n", dato);
    
    pthread_exit((void*)&dato);
}
```

`dato` no longer exists as soon as the function returns. By taking the address of that variable and dereferencing it after the function returns (back in the `main` thread), you're invoking undefined behavior.

You can either:

- Cast the `float` to `void *` and return the *value* directly (as if it were a pointer) and cast it back to `float` in `main`.

  - This may break some rules (is a `void *` guaranteed to be big enough to hold a `float`?), but I've seen this used often.
- Allocate an object using `malloc` and return that pointer.

---

First option:

```c
void* stampa(void* arg) {
    float dato = *(float*)arg;
    printf("Read: %f\n", dato);
    
    pthread_exit((void*)dato);
}

// Main
int main() {
    system("clear");

    pthread_t miot;
    int creathread;
    float x;
    float status;

    printf("Number: ");
    scanf("%f", &x);

    creathread = pthread_create(&miot, NULL, stampa, (void*)&x);

    if (creathread != 0) {
        printf("Error\n");
    }

    pthread_join(miot, (void*)&status);
    printf("Returned: %f\n", status);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It throws an error if I compile it like this: arg.c: In function ‘stampa’:
arg.c:13:2: error: cannot convert to a pointer type
  pthread_exit((void*)dato);